# Inheritance in Solidity

Tags: inheritance, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

```
contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Permit, ERC20Votes {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") ERC20Permit("MyToken") {}

   // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _afterTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function _mint(address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._burn(account, amount);
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain why we need to override these 4 functions from base contract ?
It's not possible to call it from `super` keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain on this

```
 function _afterTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }
```

Normally, `super._afterTokenTransfer` will check parent contracts, find `_afterTokenTransfer` function and call it. But if your contract is inheriting from multiple contracts, and more than one contract has the same function, it will inherit from the right-most contract first. But since you have this:

```
 override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
```

it will visit both the contract and call `_afterTokenTransfer` inside each contract. If you did not have this `override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)`

```
 function _afterTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
            internal
            override
        {
            super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
        }
```

since the right-most parent contract is `ERC20Votes`, `super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount)` this will call only from `ERC20Votes`